# NSString is being truncated

Tags: ios, soap, nsstring, truncate, string-length

In my app I am using a webservice that sign a document. I have to send the documento in base64format inside the SOAP call. The problem is that when I try to send a big document like a 11mb one, the base64 (stored in a NSString) is to large and the SOAP message is truncated.

Because of that I can send the SOAP call propertly and I recive a server error.

Is there any class that can store a large (very large) string?

**EDIT: This is the code i've used:**

To convert the document to base64:

```
NSData *signData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:self.pathDocument];
NSString *base64file = [signData base64EncodedString];
```

To perform the call:

```
NSString *soapMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\" xmlns:seal=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07\">"
                   "<soapenv:Header/>"
                   "<soapenv:Body>"
                   "<tem:Sign>"
                   "<tem:type>Signature</tem:type>"
                   "<tem:biometricState>%@</tem:biometricState>"
                   "<tem:idCertificate>%d</tem:idCertificate>"
                   "<tem:signatureProfile>%@</tem:signatureProfile>"
                   "<tem:signatureType>Default</tem:signatureType>"
                   "<tem:hashAlgorithm>Default</tem:hashAlgorithm>"
                   "<tem:options>%@</tem:options>"
                   "<tem:signingDocument>%@</tem:signingDocument>"
                   "</tem:Sign>"
                   "</soapenv:Body>"
                   "</soapenv:Envelope>",
                   aSign,
                   [aCertificado idCert],
                   tipoFirma,
                   flagFirma,
                   aDocument
                   ];

NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@//Service/SignatureServiceBasic.svc", [settings servidor]];
    NSURL *sRequestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:sRequestURL];
    NSString *sMessageLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMsg length]];

    [myRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [myRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/ISignatureServiceBasic/Sign" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [myRequest addValue: sMessageLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [myRequest addValue:@"Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
    [myRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSString* username = [settings usuario];
    NSString* password = [settings pass];

    NSString *authStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@", username, password];
    NSData *authData = [authStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *authValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Basic %@", [authData base64EncodingWithLineLength:80]];
    [myRequest setValue:authValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];


    signConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];

    if( signConnection ) {
        webResponseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Some error occurred in Connection");

    }
```

`aDocument` is the document in base64.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: NSString can store any size, provided it fits into memory. You may find your issue elsewhere.  You should show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem.
Sorry, I had misunderstood the problem. All my code was ok, the problem was due to a service parameter (in the IIS) that controls the maximum size of the files that can be uploaded.

Xcode crashed and failed on memory because the app was in debug mode. Without using the debugger, it does not.

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1):

NO there is no such class.. but you can try 1 thing 
Try creating your data in chunks instead of a big file and send that data to server using streams..

Comment: thanks, i am trying to find some example of how to chunk the data but i don't find anyone, i will edit the question with my code (2 min)

Comment: YOu can look at NSURLRequest `- (NSInputStream *)HTTPBodyStream` function to check how to upload data using streams. I hope this will help you a lot with your problem..

Answer (score 0):

You should send such large resource in form of attachments rather than as body of request. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) library provides ready to consume functions for same.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "attachment" in a HTTP message. The body is perfectly fine for sending huge data, possibly using "chunked transfer encoding".